# Mysql Adding values in a column based on values in other column

Tags: mysql

[image: Payment Table]

What is the mysql query to get the below result from the table?. Addition in the amount column should be carried out based on the invoiceID.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ID, InvoiceID, SUM(AMOUNT) 
FROM <tablename>, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
GROUP BY InvoiceID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select  @i:=@i+1 AS id,a.*
     from
     (select InvoiceID,sum(Amount) as Amount
      from your_table
      group by InvoiceID)a,(SELECT @i:=0) r
```

## [SQL Fiddel demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bab4f/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,InvoiceID, SUM(Amount)
from <table>
group by InvoiceID
```